# How to convert req.body to model in ES6 to match the database columns when using knex js? - Javascript

Tags: node.js, express, javascript-objects, knex.js, es6-class

I am working on a node js with es6.
I have a table which has few fields. I am using knex js for query building and db management.
My Doubt is how can I set the fields by sending req.body object to es6 class constructor?
Eg.

```
class User {
  constructor(user_id, email, username, password, phone, first_name, last_name, created_at, created_by, updated_at, updated_by){
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.email = email;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.last_name = last_name;
    this.created_at = created_at;
    this.created_by = created_by;
    this.updated_at = updated_at;
    this.updated_by = updated_by;
  }

  get _user_id(){
      return this.user_id;
  }

  set _user_id(user_id){
      this.user_id = user_id;
  }

  get _email(){
      return this.email;
  }

  set _email(email){
      this.email = email;
  }

  get _username(){
      return this.username;
  }

  set _username(username){
      this.username = username;
  }

  get _password(){
      return this.password;
  }

  set _password(password){
      this.password = password;
  }

  get _phone(){
      return this.phone;
  }

  set _phone(phone){
      this.phone = phone;
  }

  get _first_name(){
      return this.first_name;
  }

  set _first_name(first_name){
      this.first_name = first_name;
  }

  get _last_name(){
      return this.last_name;
  }

  set _last_name(last_name){
      this.last_name = last_name;
  }

  get _created_at(){
      return this.created_at;
  }

  set _created_at(created_at){
      this.created_at = created_at;
  }

  get _created_by(){
      return this.created_by;
  }

  set _created_by(created_by){
      this.created_by = created_by;
  }

  get _updated_at(){
      return this.updated_at;
  }

  set _updated_at(updated_at){
      this.updated_at = updated_at;
  }

  get _updated_by(){
      return this.updated_by;
  }

  set _updated_by(updated_by){
      this.updated_by = updated_by;
  }
}

export default User;
```

In java we can do this with pojo objects.
and use `User user = new User(arg1, arg2 ...);`
In es6 using above code I can do `let user = new User(arg1, arg2...);`

Now I can use

```
knex.insert(user).then((data) => {
}, (err) =>{
});
```

But is there a better way to create objects like this in es6?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer working with plain objects instead of wrapping them in classes. In your example you typed 105 lines of code that do pretty much nothing. And it's much easier working with raw data instead of abstractions around it.

So basically my recipe is:

- Working with class/wrapper around data object → working with data object itself
- `get myField` → `object.myField`
- `set myField` → `object.myField = myValue`

And your example becomes trivial

```
knex('users')
    .insert(req.body) // Or you may want to cleanup body before inserting or smth.
    .returning('*')
    .then((data) => {
        data.password = null;
        console.log('User created %j', data)
        res.json(data).status(200)
    })
```

Comment: I have created the class to set only those properties that are required for my database. So that all other extra body params are not set on the new object.

Comment: You can always pick raw properties whichever you need like `.insert({ email: req.body.email, username: req.body.username ... })` or use  widely used (maybe even essential) library [lodash.pick](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick) like `_.pick(req.body, ['email', 'username', ...]) // => { email: 'somevalue', username: 'value', ...}`